# get selected item from selectList and passing to controller

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionsupport, selectlist

I'm trying to get the value of selected list and passing it to the controller but my code does not work !
I have tried to do this.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!facility}" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!FacilityOptions}" />
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange">
                       <apex:param name="selectedVal" value="{!facility.Name__c}" assignTo="{!facilityName}"/>
                   </apex:actionSupport>
 </apex:selectList>
```

Controller:

```
public List<Facility__c> facilities {set; get;}
public Facility__c facility {get;set;}

 public List<SelectOption> getFacilityOptions() {

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (Facility__c record : getfacilities())
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(record.Name,record.Name__c));
    }
    return options;
    }


public List<Facility__c> getfacilities(){
   facilities = [SELECT Name,Name__c FROM Facility__c];

   return facilities;
}
```

Comment: The value is passed to the property specified by the merge field in the `value` parameter when the page is submitted.  Can you post your controller code?  At least the portions dealing with `facility` and `FacilityOptions`.  Without that I can't provide a more precise answer.  Also, are you simply trying to pass this value back when the form is submitted, or do you need invoke a controller behavior each time the selectList changes?

Comment: I added some code of controller, I want to get value on submit the whole form, but I'm using onChange to assign the value when I change it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing the action parameter of the actionSupport tag of visualforce. Try calling a method in action parameter of actionsupport and take a look at the value of variable in debug logs. Also you can perform operations in that method you wish to do on change event.

Comment: I tried to call action, but I think the problem in my code is in the logic ! I'm new in VF, VF logic still unknown for me.